# Problem with savesym

Tags: warnings, ctan

MWE:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}

\usepackage{savesym}

\begin{document}
content...
\end{document}
```

Gets the following error ``` You have requested package ``savesym',but the package provides ``savesymbol'. ```
If I look at the sty file it's clear the typo however in CTAN there's no mail to tell the developer.

Comment: I would assume the same is true of [`MnSymbol`](http://ctan.org/pkg/mnsymbol). It is truly bizarre to need to use `\usepackage{MnSymbol}` rather than `\usepackage{mnsymbol}`...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If a package is on CTAN, then you can ask the CTAN managers to forward a mail from you to the package maintainer, because the CTAN managers maintain a data base of the email addresses of the contributors.

In case of package `savesym` you can try the email address, that can be found in the package file `savesym.sty`. But the package is more than ten years old, thus the address might be out of date. In the mailing list TEX-D-L he is using a different address.

Comment: I have now notified the maintainer of package `savesym`.

Comment: ok, thanks. Normally there's the mail on the ctan page of the package but this was not the case and I forgot to look in the sty